# Constraint programming suitable for extracting OneToMany relationships from records

Tags: prolog, constraints, constraint-programming

Maybe someone can help me to solve a problem with Prolog or any constraint programming language. Imagine a table of projects (school projects where pupils do something with their mothers). Each project has one or more children participating. For each child we store its name and the name of its mother. But for each project there is only one cell that contains all mothers and one cell that contains all children. Both cells are not necessarily ordered in the same way.

Example:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|           |           |            |
|   Project |   Parents |   Children |
|           |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|           |           |            |
|   1       |   Jane;   |   Brian;   |
|           |   Claire  |   Stephen  |
|           |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|           |           |            |
|   2       |   Claire; |   Emma;    |
|           |   Jane    |   William  |
|           |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|           |           |            |
|   3       |   Jane;   |   William; |
|           |   Claire  |   James    |
|           |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|           |           |            |
|   4       |   Jane;   |   Brian;   |
|           |   Sophia; |   James;   |
|           |   Claire  |   Isabella |
|           |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|           |           |            |
|   4       |   Claire  |   Brian    |
|           |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|           |           |            |
|   5       |   Jane    |   Emma     |
|           |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I hope this example visualizes the problem. As I said both cells only contain the names separated by a delimiter, but are not necessarily ordered in a similar way. So for technical applications you would transform the data into this:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   Project   |   Name    |   Role   |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1         |   Jane    |   Mother |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1         |   Claire  |   Mother |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1         |   Brian   |   Child  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1         |   Stephen |   Child  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   2         |   Jane    |   Mother |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   2         |   Claire  |   Mother |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   2         |   Emma    |   Child  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   2         |   William |   Child  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|             |           |          |
|                                    |
|              And so on             |
```

The number of parents and children is equal for each project. So for each deal we have n mothers and n children and each mother belongs to exactly one child. With these constraints it is possible to assign each mother to all of her children by logical inference starting with the projects that involve only one child (i.e. 4 and 5).

Results:

Jane has Emma, Stephen and James;

Claire has Brian and William;

Sophia has Isabella

I am wondering how this can be solved using constraint programming. Additionally, the data set might be underdetermined and I am wondering if it is possible to isolate records that, when solved manually (i.e. when the mother-child assignments are done manually), would break the underdetermination.

Comment: I have to admit that I wasn't able to understand your data. Can you describe it maybe in normal form? Like, how would you model it if you had a relational database?

Comment: I second @User9213 in that I can't quite make sense of your data. You say Claire has Emma but in group 5 Jane has Emma. Following from the data you show, I get a contradiction between Jane and Claire over James but I just don't agree with what you have except that Sophia has Isabella.

Comment: You are totally right. While I was fighting with alignment of the ASCII table, I made a mistake. Hopefully it gets clearer now. The key problem is that both cells are not ordered in a similar way (at least not necessarily). I have added how it would look in normal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand all the requirements of the problem, but here is a constraint programming model in MiniZinc (http://www.minizinc.org/). The full model is here: http://hakank.org/minizinc/one_to_many.mzn .

LATER NOTE: The first version of the project constraints where not correct. I have removed the incorrect code . See the edit history for the original answer.

```
enum mothers = {jane,claire,sophia};
enum children = {brian,stephen,emma,william,james,isabella};      

% decision variables

% who is the mother of this child?
array[children] of var mothers: x;


solve satisfy;

constraint
  % All mothers has at least one child
  forall(m in mothers) (
    exists(c in children) (
      x[c] = m
    )
  )
;

constraint
% NOTE: This is a more correct version of the project constraints.
% project 1
(
  ( x[brian] = jane /\ x[stephen] = claire) \/
  ( x[stephen] = jane /\ x[brian] = claire)
) 
/\
% project 2
(
  ( x[emma] = claire /\ x[william] = jane) \/
  ( x[william] = claire /\ x[emma] = jane) 
)
/\
% project 3
(
  ( x[william] = claire /\ x[james] = jane) \/
  ( x[james] = claire /\ x[william] = jane) 
)
/\
% project 4
( 
  ( x[brian] = jane /\ x[james] = sophia /\ x[isabella] = claire) \/
  ( x[james] = jane /\ x[brian] = sophia /\ x[isabella] = claire) \/
  ( x[james] = jane /\ x[isabella] = sophia /\ x[brian] = claire) \/
  ( x[brian] = jane /\ x[isabella] = sophia /\ x[james] = claire) \/
  ( x[isabella] = jane /\ x[brian] = sophia /\ x[james] = claire) \/
  ( x[isabella] = jane /\ x[james] = sophia /\ x[brian] = claire) 
)
/\

% project 4(sic!)
( x[brian] = claire) /\

% project 5
( x[emma] = jane)
;


output [
  "\(c): \(x[c])\n"
  | c in children
];
```

The unique solution is

```
brian: claire
stephen: jane
emma: jane
william: claire
james: jane
isabella: sophia
```

Edit2: Here is a more general solution. See http://hakank.org/minizinc/one_to_many.mzn for the complete model.

```
include "globals.mzn"; 

enum mothers = {jane,claire,sophia};
enum children = {brian,stephen,emma,william,james,isabella};      

% decision variables
% who is the mother of this child?
array[children] of var mothers: x;

% combine all the combinations of mothers and children in a project
predicate check(array[int] of mothers: mm, array[int] of children: cc) =
  let {
    int: n = length(mm);
    array[1..n] of var 1..n: y;
  } in
  all_different(y) /\
  forall(i in 1..n) (
     x[cc[i]] = mm[y[i]]
  )
;    

solve satisfy;

constraint
% All mothers has at least one child.
forall(m in mothers) (
  exists(c in children) (
    x[c] = m
  )
)
;


constraint
% project 1    
check([jane,claire], [brian,stephen]) /\
% project 2
check([claire,jane],[emma,william]) /\
% project 3
check([claire,jane],[william,james]) /\
% project 4
check([claire,sophia,jane],[brian,james,isabella]) /\
% project 4(sic!)
check([claire],[brian]) /\
% project 5
check([jane],[emma])
;

output [
 "\(c): \(x[c])\n"
 | c in children
];
```

This model use the following predicate to ensure that all the combinations of mothers vs children are considered:

```
predicate check(array[int] of mothers: mm, array[int] of children: cc) =
   let {
     int: n = length(mm);
     array[1..n] of var 1..n: y;
  } in
  all_different(y) /\
  forall(i in 1..n) (
    x[cc[i]] = mm[y[i]]
  )
;
```

It use the global constraint `all_different(y)` to ensure that `mm[y[i]]` is one of the mothers in `mm`, and then assign the `i'th child to that specific mother.

Comment: Thank you! As I said, I don't have experience with constraint programming, but that already looks really close to what I am looking for. What is missing however is the constraint that within one project each mother belongs to exactly one child. For example in your first solution both William and Emma belong to Jane. This would mean for project 2 that both children belong to only one mother (Jane) and the other mother (Claire) is listed there without a corresping child. With this additional constraint there should be only one solution if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Ah, of course! I got the `and` and `or` the wrong way in the project constraints. The model is now updated with a "brute force" approach, which is not that elegant since one have to explicitly enumerate all combinations.

Comment: Thank you again, The solution looks good, since it also means that in case the problem is underdetermined and there are several solutions possible, I can just check the delta between the solutions in order to isolate the specific relations that I need to assign manually to break the underdetermination. I will dig deeper into that and see how I can use it for larger problems of the same kind.

Comment: And I just added a more general model where you don't have to enumerate all the permutations. It yield the same unique result as the previous one. Regarding underdetermination: yes, this model will generate all the solutions that satisfies the constraints.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Here's a Picat model: http://hakank.org/picat/one_to_many.pi It includes two approaches: go/0 is an approach using Picat's foreach loops and indexing; go2/0 is without loops or indexing.

Answer (score 1):

A bit off topic, but since from [SWI-Prolog manual](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clp):

> Plain Prolog can be regarded as CLP(H), where H stands for Herbrand
>   terms. Over this domain, =/2 and dif/2 are the most important
>   constraints that express, respectively, equality and disequality of
>   terms.

I feel authorized to suggest a Prolog solution, more general than the algorithm you suggested (progressively reduce relations based on single to single relations):

```erlang
solve2(Projects,ParentsChildren) :-
    foldl([_-Ps-Cs,L,L1]>>try_links(Ps,Cs,L,L1),Projects,[],ChildrenParent),
    transpose_pairs(ChildrenParent,ParentsChildrenFlat),
    group_pairs_by_key(ParentsChildrenFlat,ParentsChildren).

try_links([],[],Linked,Linked).
try_links(Ps,Cs,Linked,Linked2) :-
    select(P,Ps,Ps1),
    select(C,Cs,Cs1),
    link(C,P,Linked,Linked1),
    try_links(Ps1,Cs1,Linked1,Linked2).

link(C,P,Assigned,Assigned1) :-
    (   memberchk(C-Q,Assigned)
    ->  P==Q,
        Assigned1=Assigned
    ;   Assigned1=[C-P|Assigned]
    ).
```

This accepts data in a natural format, like

```erlang
data(1,
    [1-[jane,claire]-[brian,stephen]
    ,2-[claire,jane]-[emma,william]
    ,3-[jane,claire]-[william,james]
    ,4-[jane,sophia,claire]-[brian,james,isabella]
    ,5-[claire]-[brian]
    ,6-[jane]-[emma]
    ]).
data(2,
    [1-[jane,claire]-[brian,stephen]
    ,2-[claire,jane]-[emma,william]
    ,3-[jane,claire]-[william,james]
    ,4-[jane,sophia,claire]-[brian,james,isabella]
    ,5-[claire]-[brian]
    ,6-[jane]-[emma]
    ,7-[sally,sandy]-[grace,miriam]
    ]).

?- data(2,Ps),solve2(Ps,S).
Ps = [1-[jane, claire]-[brian, stephen], 2-[claire, jane]-[emma, william], 3-[jane, claire]-[william, james], 4-[jane, sophia, claire]-[brian, james, isabella], 5-[claire]-[brian], 6-[jane]-[emma], 7-[...|...]-[grace|...]],
S = [claire-[william, brian], jane-[james, emma, stephen], sally-[grace], sandy-[miriam], sophia-[isabella]].
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first CHR program, so I hope that someone will come and give me some advice on how to improve it.

My thinking is that you need to expand all the lists into facts. From there, if you know that a project has just one parent and one child, you can establish the parent relationship from that. Also, once you have a parent-child relationship, you can remove that set from the other facts in the other projects and reduce the cardinality of the problem by one. Eventually you will have figured out everything you can. The only difference between a completely determined dataset and an incompletely determined one is in how far that reduction can go. If it doesn't quite get there, it will leave around some facts so you can see which projects/parents/children are still creating ambiguity.

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- chr_constraint project/3, project_parent/2, project_child/2, 
   project_parents/2, project_children/2, project_size/2, parent/2.

%% turn a project into a fact about its size plus 
%% facts for each parent and child in this project
project(N, Parents, Children) <=>
    length(Parents, Len),
    project_size(N, Len),
    project_parents(N, Parents),
    project_children(N, Children).

%% expand the list of parents for this project into a fact per parent per project
project_parents(_, []) <=> true.
project_parents(N, [Parent|Parents]) <=>
    project_parent(N, Parent),
    project_parents(N, Parents).

%% same for the children
project_children(_, []) <=> true.
project_children(N, [Child|Children]) <=>
    project_child(N, Child),
    project_children(N, Children).

%% a single parent-child combo on a project is exactly what we need
one_parent @ project_size(Project, 1), 
             project_parent(Project, Parent), 
             project_child(Project, Child) <=>
    parent(Parent, Child).

%% if I have a parent relationship for project of size N,
%% remove this parent and child from the project and decrease
%% the number of parents and children by one
parent_det @ parent(Parent, Child) \ project_size(Project, N), 
                                     project_parent(Project, Parent), 
                                     project_child(Project, Child) <=>
    succ(N0, N),
    project_size(Project, N0).
```

I ran this with your example by making a `main/0` predicate to do it:

```
main :-
    project(1, [jane, claire], [brian, stephen]),
    project(2, [claire, jane], [emma, william]),
    project(3, [jane, claire], [william, james]),
    project(4, [jane, sophia, claire], [brian, james, isabella]),
    project(5, [claire], [brian]),
    project(6, [jane], [emma]).
```

This outputs:

```
parent(sophia, isabella),
parent(jane, james),
parent(claire, william),
parent(jane, emma),
parent(jane, stephen),
parent(claire, brian).
```

To demonstrate incomplete determination, I added a seventh project:

```
project(7, [sally,sandy], [grace,miriam]).
```

The program then outputs this:

```
project_parent(7, sandy),
project_parent(7, sally),
project_child(7, miriam),
project_child(7, grace),
project_size(7, 2),
parent(sophia, isabella),
parent(jane, james),
parent(claire, william),
parent(jane, emma),
parent(jane, stephen),
parent(claire, brian).
```

As you can see, any `project_size/2` that remains tells you the cardinality of what remains to be solved (project seven has two parent/children relationships still remaining to be determined) and you get back exactly the parents/children that remain to be handled, as well as all of the `parent/2` relations which could be determined.

I'm pretty happy with this outcome but hopefully others can come and improve my code!

**Edit**: my code has a shortcoming which was identified on the mailing list, that certain inputs will fail to converge even though the solution can be computed, for instance:

```
project(1,[jane,claire],[brian, stephan]),
project(2,[jane,emma],[stephan, jones]).
```

For more information, see [Ian's solution](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/please-review-my-first-chr-program/911/3), which uses set intersection to determine the mapping.