# What's the equivalent of a map function in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, map-function, meta-predicate

If I have a list, and want to produce a list with all items transformed by a "function", eg, the equivalent of Lisp's

```
(map f xs)
```

How do I do the equivalent in Prolog?

Comment: I didn't mean for that to sound rude but it kind of does. It's hard to get your bearings in Prolog, but questions like this are more of a "making the map of the land of Prolog" and are not as well suited to Stack Overflow as a "how do I solve this particular problem." You will probably get a warmer reception on [the SWI Prolog discourse](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) and feel free to email me directly (email in profile) if you want to talk about Prolog without worrying about making good Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: I would argue that most of the interesting questions lately under this tag are things you would not be able to find in the documentation, like [this one about N-queens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56221482), [this one about reifying backtracking state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57053568) and [this one about constraint programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56843065). Documentation lookups like this one tend not to get any votes in the [tag:prolog] tag.